# Android - checked perform action

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

As I'm new to android, My problem is I'm Developing an application I want to increment/decrement the numbers by clicking on the buttons in the home page,but first of all it should check for in the settings menu the check box is checked,if it is checked then only to perform the actions...[image: Settings menu][image: Home page]

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sanple;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public Button incre;
    public Button dec;
    public TextView nub;
    public static int count = 0;
    public String string;

    /*
     * @Override protected void onStart() { super.onStart();
     * 
     * Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); if (bundle != null) { if
     * (bundle.getBoolean("checked")) { MainActivity activity = new
     * MainActivity(); activity.addListenerOnCheckbox(); } else {
     * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "try to check the checkbox",
     * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
     * 
     * } }
     */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnCheckbox();

        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    }

    void addListenerOnCheckbox() {
        incre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increment);
        dec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decrement);
        nub = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brakecounter);

        incre.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("src", "button clciked");
                count++;
                string = Integer.toString(count);
                nub.setText(string);
            }
        });

        dec.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("src", "button clciked");
                count--;
                string = Integer.toString(count);
                nub.setText(string);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();
        int keycode = event.getKeyCode();
        switch (keycode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                int i = count++;
                if (i > 10) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "applying too many times brake", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }
                string = Integer.toString(count);
                nub.setText(string);

            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                count--;
                string = Integer.toString(count);
                nub.setText(string);

            }

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // MenuInflater inflater = new MenuInflater(getApplicationContext());
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent startActivity = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(startActivity);

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Settings.java

```
package com.example.sanple;

import android.R.color;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Settings extends Activity {

    public TextView view;
    public CheckBox box;
    public Button button;

    // KeyEvent KeyEvent = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.enable_counter);
        box = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        box.setBackgroundColor(color.black);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        box.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                /*//here we r setting checked true
                box.setChecked(true);
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("Checked", true);*/

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Check Box xml..

activity_settings.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Settings" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/enable_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="enable_counter"
        android:textColor="#f00" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/enable_counter"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/enable_counter"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="39dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
        android:text="save" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this, in your button click event code :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent startActivity = new Intent(this, Settings.class);
            startActivityForResult(startActivity);

            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

In settings do this :

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                             boolean isChecked) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(isChecked)
      intent.putExtra("Checked", true);
    else
      intent.putExtra("Checked",false);
             setResult(i,100);
}
```

//put this in main activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == 100) {
               boolean val = data.getBooleanExtra("checked",false);
               if(val==true)
               //allow to increment decrement
               else
               //not
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: check your checkbox id

Comment: try to set listener for it and define a boolean variable and check if its true then do your work. see example here for listener.http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-checkbox-example/

Comment: i even seen this example it don't match to me..'

Comment: your checkbox is in differenct activity and button in different activity, right.?

Comment: yaa.. that correct..now what should i do can you help me i'm struggling from yesterday..

Comment: first which screen is launching .Mainactivity or settings. ? if maina ctivity then when you navigate to settings.java and when you set checkbox you should use here startactivityforresult.

Comment: that what I'm saying is, if the check box is checked then allow him to increment./decrement the buttons..

Comment: k i will try to implement. if any problem i ll ping you..thank you

Comment: what you are getting now.

Comment: where did you add onactivityresult method?. it should be in mainactivity class.

Comment: @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int i, Intent intent) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, i, intent);
 }

Comment: you can do something like diable button at start and when user click on checkbox , check in onactivityresult , if check == true enable the button else leave it disable.

Comment: i am at officeright now. i will be able to help you when i will be at home.

Comment: try enabling disabling button.

Comment: yes. its not that difficult . i dont know why you are not able to make it work..:P

Comment: and im not sir , my name is waqar.

Comment: like when the app starts it should check for in settings menu the check box is enabled or not ,if enabled try to inc/dec other wise no..

Comment: try using sharedpreference too.

Comment: it will become easier with sharedpreferences